# SSH Invalid key length on embedded device

Tags: ssh

I'm trying to SSH into a device but I kept getting an error prior to authentication, namely "Invalid key length". I am scared to modify the device as I don't know what horrors that lie within are needed for it to work. Case in point: It seems that the manufacturer runs their entire GUI inside an Android app, that launches automatically shortly after startup, on Android 2.2, that runs on top of *something* that likes to show Tux when it boots.

What should I do to get SSH to even attempt to authenticate?

## SSH - Debug:3

```
OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.1, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "192.168.1.120" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.1.120 [192.168.1.120] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/husky/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/husky/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/husky/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/husky/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/husky/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/husky/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/husky/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/husky/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version dropbear_2012.55
debug1: no match: dropbear_2012.55
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to 192.168.1.120:22 as 'user'
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: diffie-hellman-group1-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: aes128-ctr,3des-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,aes256-cbc,twofish256-cbc,twofish-cbc,twofish128-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: aes128-ctr,3des-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,aes256-cbc,twofish256-cbc,twofish-cbc,twofish128-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-sha1-96,hmac-sha1,hmac-md5
debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-sha1-96,hmac-sha1,hmac-md5
debug2: compression ctos: zlib,zlib@openssh.com,none
debug2: compression stoc: zlib,zlib@openssh.com,none
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug1: kex: algorithm: diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-rsa
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha1 compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha1 compression: none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEXDH_INIT
debug2: bits set: 1022/2048
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEXDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
ssh_dispatch_run_fatal: Connection to 192.168.1.120 port 22: Invalid key length
```

## Associated TCPDump -X Output

```
19:17:38.268011 IP husky-MS-7921.40324 > 9774d56d682e549c.ssh: Flags [S], seq 2347624957, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 2322116349 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
    0x0000:  4500 003c af22 4000 4006 0768 c0a8 0169  E..<."@.@..h...i
    0x0010:  c0a8 0178 9d84 0016 8bed e9fd 0000 0000  ...x............
    0x0020:  a002 7210 04d2 0000 0204 05b4 0402 080a  ..r.............
    0x0030:  8a68 aefd 0000 0000 0103 0307            .h..........
19:17:39.096971 IP 9774d56d682e549c.ssh > husky-MS-7921.40324: Flags [S.], seq 1797888426, ack 2347624958, win 5792, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 1805575304 ecr 2322116349,nop,wscale 1], length 0
    0x0000:  4510 003c 0000 4000 4006 b67a c0a8 0178  E..<..@.@..z...x
    0x0010:  c0a8 0169 0016 9d84 6b29 99aa 8bed e9fe  ...i....k)......
    0x0020:  a012 16a0 0b3c 0000 0204 05b4 0402 080a  .....<..........
    0x0030:  6b9e e488 8a68 aefd 0103 0301            k....h......
19:17:39.097047 IP husky-MS-7921.40324 > 9774d56d682e549c.ssh: Flags [.], ack 1, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 2322117178 ecr 1805575304], length 0
    0x0000:  4500 0034 af23 4000 4006 076f c0a8 0169  E..4.#@.@..o...i
    0x0010:  c0a8 0178 9d84 0016 8bed e9fe 6b29 99ab  ...x........k)..
    0x0020:  8010 00e5 4c80 0000 0101 080a 8a68 b23a  ....L........h.:
    0x0030:  6b9e e488                                k...
19:17:39.097935 IP husky-MS-7921.40324 > 9774d56d682e549c.ssh: Flags [P.], seq 1:42, ack 1, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 2322117179 ecr 1805575304], length 41
    0x0000:  4500 005d af24 4000 4006 0745 c0a8 0169  E..].$@.@..E...i
    0x0010:  c0a8 0178 9d84 0016 8bed e9fe 6b29 99ab  ...x........k)..
    0x0020:  8018 00e5 2826 0000 0101 080a 8a68 b23b  ....(&.......h.;
    0x0030:  6b9e e488 5353 482d 322e 302d 4f70 656e  k...SSH-2.0-Open
    0x0040:  5353 485f 372e 3670 3120 5562 756e 7475  SSH_7.6p1.Ubuntu
    0x0050:  2d34 7562 756e 7475 302e 310d 0a         -4ubuntu0.1..
19:17:39.102981 IP 9774d56d682e549c.ssh > husky-MS-7921.40324: Flags [.], ack 42, win 2896, options [nop,nop,TS val 1805575305 ecr 2322117179], length 0
    0x0000:  4510 0034 7d22 4000 4006 3960 c0a8 0178  E..4}"@.@.9`...x
    0x0010:  c0a8 0169 0016 9d84 6b29 99ab 8bed ea27  ...i....k).....'
    0x0020:  8010 0b50 41ea 0000 0101 080a 6b9e e489  ...PA.......k...
    0x0030:  8a68 b23b                                .h.;
19:17:39.121765 IP 9774d56d682e549c.ssh > husky-MS-7921.40324: Flags [P.], seq 1:27, ack 42, win 2896, options [nop,nop,TS val 1805575308 ecr 2322117179], length 26
    0x0000:  4510 004e 7d23 4000 4006 3945 c0a8 0178  E..N}#@.@.9E...x
    0x0010:  c0a8 0169 0016 9d84 6b29 99ab 8bed ea27  ...i....k).....'
    0x0020:  8018 0b50 a85d 0000 0101 080a 6b9e e48c  ...P.]......k...
    0x0030:  8a68 b23b 5353 482d 322e 302d 6472 6f70  .h.;SSH-2.0-drop
    0x0040:  6265 6172 5f32 3031 322e 3535 0d0a       bear_2012.55..
19:17:39.121807 IP husky-MS-7921.40324 > 9774d56d682e549c.ssh: Flags [.], ack 27, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 2322117202 ecr 1805575308], length 0
    0x0000:  4500 0034 af25 4000 4006 076d c0a8 0169  E..4.%@.@..m...i
    0x0010:  c0a8 0178 9d84 0016 8bed ea27 6b29 99c5  ...x.......'k)..
    0x0020:  8010 00e5 4c21 0000 0101 080a 8a68 b252  ....L!.......h.R
    0x0030:  6b9e e48c                                k...
19:17:39.121832 IP 9774d56d682e549c.ssh > husky-MS-7921.40324: Flags [P.], seq 27:483, ack 42, win 2896, options [nop,nop,TS val 1805575308 ecr 2322117179], length 456
    0x0000:  4510 01fc 7d24 4000 4006 3796 c0a8 0178  E...}$@.@.7....x
    0x0010:  c0a8 0169 0016 9d84 6b29 99c5 8bed ea27  ...i....k).....'
    0x0020:  8018 0b50 bd12 0000 0101 080a 6b9e e48c  ...P........k...
    0x0030:  8a68 b23b 0000 01c4 0814 ff98 9878 b227  .h.;.........x.'
    0x0040:  b6e9 0ef3 a65a 7d13 a857 0000 0036 6469  .....Z}..W...6di
    0x0050:  6666 6965 2d68 656c 6c6d 616e 2d67 726f  ffie-hellman-gro
    0x0060:  7570 312d 7368 6131 2c64 6966 6669 652d  up1-sha1,diffie-
    0x0070:  6865 6c6c 6d61 6e2d 6772 6f75 7031 342d  hellman-group14-
    0x0080:  7368 6131 0000 0007 7373 682d 7273 6100  sha1....ssh-rsa.
    0x0090:  0000 6761 6573 3132 382d 6374 722c 3364  ..gaes128-ctr,3d
    0x00a0:  6573 2d63 7472 2c61 6573 3235 362d 6374  es-ctr,aes256-ct
    0x00b0:  722c 6165 7331 3238 2d63 6263 2c33 6465  r,aes128-cbc,3de
    0x00c0:  732d 6362 632c 6165 7332 3536 2d63 6263  s-cbc,aes256-cbc
    0x00d0:  2c74 776f 6669 7368 3235 362d 6362 632c  ,twofish256-cbc,
    0x00e0:  7477 6f66 6973 682d 6362 632c 7477 6f66  twofish-cbc,twof
    0x00f0:  6973 6831 3238 2d63 6263 0000 0067 6165  ish128-cbc...gae
    0x0100:  7331 3238 2d63 7472 2c33 6465 732d 6374  s128-ctr,3des-ct
    0x0110:  722c 6165 7332 3536 2d63 7472 2c61 6573  r,aes256-ctr,aes
    0x0120:  3132 382d 6362 632c 3364 6573 2d63 6263  128-cbc,3des-cbc
    0x0130:  2c61 6573 3235 362d 6362 632c 7477 6f66  ,aes256-cbc,twof
    0x0140:  6973 6832 3536 2d63 6263 2c74 776f 6669  ish256-cbc,twofi
    0x0150:  7368 2d63 6263 2c74 776f 6669 7368 3132  sh-cbc,twofish12
    0x0160:  382d 6362 6300 0000 1f68 6d61 632d 7368  8-cbc....hmac-sh
    0x0170:  6131 2d39 362c 686d 6163 2d73 6861 312c  a1-96,hmac-sha1,
    0x0180:  686d 6163 2d6d 6435 0000 001f 686d 6163  hmac-md5....hmac
    0x0190:  2d73 6861 312d 3936 2c68 6d61 632d 7368  -sha1-96,hmac-sh
    0x01a0:  6131 2c68 6d61 632d 6d64 3500 0000 1a7a  a1,hmac-md5....z
    0x01b0:  6c69 622c 7a6c 6962 406f 7065 6e73 7368  lib,zlib@openssh
    0x01c0:  2e63 6f6d 2c6e 6f6e 6500 0000 1a7a 6c69  .com,none....zli
    0x01d0:  622c 7a6c 6962 406f 7065 6e73 7368 2e63  b,zlib@openssh.c
    0x01e0:  6f6d 2c6e 6f6e 6500 0000 0000 0000 0000  om,none.........
    0x01f0:  0000 0000 50a4 878c 1985 df0f            ....P.......
19:17:39.121856 IP husky-MS-7921.40324 > 9774d56d682e549c.ssh: Flags [.], ack 483, win 237, options [nop,nop,TS val 2322117202 ecr 1805575308], length 0
    0x0000:  4500 0034 af26 4000 4006 076c c0a8 0169  E..4.&@.@..l...i
    0x0010:  c0a8 0178 9d84 0016 8bed ea27 6b29 9b8d  ...x.......'k)..
    0x0020:  8010 00ed 4a51 0000 0101 080a 8a68 b252  ....JQ.......h.R
    0x0030:  6b9e e48c                                k...
19:17:39.122372 IP husky-MS-7921.40324 > 9774d56d682e549c.ssh: Flags [P.], seq 42:1402, ack 483, win 237, options [nop,nop,TS val 2322117203 ecr 1805575308], length 1360
    0x0000:  4500 0584 af27 4000 4006 021b c0a8 0169  E....'@.@......i
    0x0010:  c0a8 0178 9d84 0016 8bed ea27 6b29 9b8d  ...x.......'k)..
    0x0020:  8018 00ed e967 0000 0101 080a 8a68 b253  .....g.......h.S
    0x0030:  6b9e e48c 0000 054c 0514 b674 9c42 6a1c  k......L...t.Bj.
    0x0040:  dc13 73aa b729 dd39 7612 0000 0130 6375  ..s..).9v....0cu
    0x0050:  7276 6532 3535 3139 2d73 6861 3235 362c  rve25519-sha256,
    0x0060:  6375 7276 6532 3535 3139 2d73 6861 3235  curve25519-sha25
    0x0070:  3640 6c69 6273 7368 2e6f 7267 2c65 6364  6@libssh.org,ecd
    0x0080:  682d 7368 6132 2d6e 6973 7470 3235 362c  h-sha2-nistp256,
    0x0090:  6563 6468 2d73 6861 322d 6e69 7374 7033  ecdh-sha2-nistp3
    0x00a0:  3834 2c65 6364 682d 7368 6132 2d6e 6973  84,ecdh-sha2-nis
    0x00b0:  7470 3532 312c 6469 6666 6965 2d68 656c  tp521,diffie-hel
    0x00c0:  6c6d 616e 2d67 726f 7570 2d65 7863 6861  lman-group-excha
    0x00d0:  6e67 652d 7368 6132 3536 2c64 6966 6669  nge-sha256,diffi
    0x00e0:  652d 6865 6c6c 6d61 6e2d 6772 6f75 7031  e-hellman-group1
    0x00f0:  362d 7368 6135 3132 2c64 6966 6669 652d  6-sha512,diffie-
    0x0100:  6865 6c6c 6d61 6e2d 6772 6f75 7031 382d  hellman-group18-
    0x0110:  7368 6135 3132 2c64 6966 6669 652d 6865  sha512,diffie-he
    0x0120:  6c6c 6d61 6e2d 6772 6f75 702d 6578 6368  llman-group-exch
    0x0130:  616e 6765 2d73 6861 312c 6469 6666 6965  ange-sha1,diffie
    0x0140:  2d68 656c 6c6d 616e 2d67 726f 7570 3134  -hellman-group14
    0x0150:  2d73 6861 3235 362c 6469 6666 6965 2d68  -sha256,diffie-h
    0x0160:  656c 6c6d 616e 2d67 726f 7570 3134 2d73  ellman-group14-s
    0x0170:  6861 312c 6578 742d 696e 666f 2d63 0000  ha1,ext-info-c..
    0x0180:  0122 6563 6473 612d 7368 6132 2d6e 6973  ."ecdsa-sha2-nis
    0x0190:  7470 3235 362d 6365 7274 2d76 3031 406f  tp256-cert-v01@o
    0x01a0:  7065 6e73 7368 2e63 6f6d 2c65 6364 7361  penssh.com,ecdsa
    0x01b0:  2d73 6861 322d 6e69 7374 7033 3834 2d63  -sha2-nistp384-c
    0x01c0:  6572 742d 7630 3140 6f70 656e 7373 682e  ert-v01@openssh.
    0x01d0:  636f 6d2c 6563 6473 612d 7368 6132 2d6e  com,ecdsa-sha2-n
    0x01e0:  6973 7470 3532 312d 6365 7274 2d76 3031  istp521-cert-v01
    0x01f0:  406f 7065 6e73 7368 2e63 6f6d 2c73 7368  @openssh.com,ssh
    0x0200:  2d65 6432 3535 3139 2d63 6572 742d 7630  -ed25519-cert-v0
    0x0210:  3140 6f70 656e 7373 682e 636f 6d2c 7373  1@openssh.com,ss
    0x0220:  682d 7273 612d 6365 7274 2d76 3031 406f  h-rsa-cert-v01@o
    0x0230:  7065 6e73 7368 2e63 6f6d 2c65 6364 7361  penssh.com,ecdsa
    0x0240:  2d73 6861 322d 6e69 7374 7032 3536 2c65  -sha2-nistp256,e
    0x0250:  6364 7361 2d73 6861 322d 6e69 7374 7033  cdsa-sha2-nistp3
    0x0260:  3834 2c65 6364 7361 2d73 6861 322d 6e69  84,ecdsa-sha2-ni
    0x0270:  7374 7035 3231 2c73 7368 2d65 6432 3535  stp521,ssh-ed255
    0x0280:  3139 2c72 7361 2d73 6861 322d 3531 322c  19,rsa-sha2-512,
    0x0290:  7273 612d 7368 6132 2d32 3536 2c73 7368  rsa-sha2-256,ssh
    0x02a0:  2d72 7361 0000 006c 6368 6163 6861 3230  -rsa...lchacha20
    0x02b0:  2d70 6f6c 7931 3330 3540 6f70 656e 7373  -poly1305@openss
    0x02c0:  682e 636f 6d2c 6165 7331 3238 2d63 7472  h.com,aes128-ctr
    0x02d0:  2c61 6573 3139 322d 6374 722c 6165 7332  ,aes192-ctr,aes2
    0x02e0:  3536 2d63 7472 2c61 6573 3132 382d 6763  56-ctr,aes128-gc
    0x02f0:  6d40 6f70 656e 7373 682e 636f 6d2c 6165  m@openssh.com,ae
    0x0300:  7332 3536 2d67 636d 406f 7065 6e73 7368  s256-gcm@openssh
    0x0310:  2e63 6f6d 0000 006c 6368 6163 6861 3230  .com...lchacha20
    0x0320:  2d70 6f6c 7931 3330 3540 6f70 656e 7373  -poly1305@openss
    0x0330:  682e 636f 6d2c 6165 7331 3238 2d63 7472  h.com,aes128-ctr
    0x0340:  2c61 6573 3139 322d 6374 722c 6165 7332  ,aes192-ctr,aes2
    0x0350:  3536 2d63 7472 2c61 6573 3132 382d 6763  56-ctr,aes128-gc
    0x0360:  6d40 6f70 656e 7373 682e 636f 6d2c 6165  m@openssh.com,ae
    0x0370:  7332 3536 2d67 636d 406f 7065 6e73 7368  s256-gcm@openssh
    0x0380:  2e63 6f6d 0000 00d5 756d 6163 2d36 342d  .com....umac-64-
    0x0390:  6574 6d40 6f70 656e 7373 682e 636f 6d2c  etm@openssh.com,
    0x03a0:  756d 6163 2d31 3238 2d65 746d 406f 7065  umac-128-etm@ope
    0x03b0:  6e73 7368 2e63 6f6d 2c68 6d61 632d 7368  nssh.com,hmac-sh
    0x03c0:  6132 2d32 3536 2d65 746d 406f 7065 6e73  a2-256-etm@opens
    0x03d0:  7368 2e63 6f6d 2c68 6d61 632d 7368 6132  sh.com,hmac-sha2
    0x03e0:  2d35 3132 2d65 746d 406f 7065 6e73 7368  -512-etm@openssh
    0x03f0:  2e63 6f6d 2c68 6d61 632d 7368 6131 2d65  .com,hmac-sha1-e
    0x0400:  746d 406f 7065 6e73 7368 2e63 6f6d 2c75  tm@openssh.com,u
    0x0410:  6d61 632d 3634 406f 7065 6e73 7368 2e63  mac-64@openssh.c
    0x0420:  6f6d 2c75 6d61 632d 3132 3840 6f70 656e  om,umac-128@open
    0x0430:  7373 682e 636f 6d2c 686d 6163 2d73 6861  ssh.com,hmac-sha
    0x0440:  322d 3235 362c 686d 6163 2d73 6861 322d  2-256,hmac-sha2-
    0x0450:  3531 322c 686d 6163 2d73 6861 3100 0000  512,hmac-sha1...
    0x0460:  d575 6d61 632d 3634 2d65 746d 406f 7065  .umac-64-etm@ope
    0x0470:  6e73 7368 2e63 6f6d 2c75 6d61 632d 3132  nssh.com,umac-12
    0x0480:  382d 6574 6d40 6f70 656e 7373 682e 636f  8-etm@openssh.co
    0x0490:  6d2c 686d 6163 2d73 6861 322d 3235 362d  m,hmac-sha2-256-
    0x04a0:  6574 6d40 6f70 656e 7373 682e 636f 6d2c  etm@openssh.com,
    0x04b0:  686d 6163 2d73 6861 322d 3531 322d 6574  hmac-sha2-512-et
    0x04c0:  6d40 6f70 656e 7373 682e 636f 6d2c 686d  m@openssh.com,hm
    0x04d0:  6163 2d73 6861 312d 6574 6d40 6f70 656e  ac-sha1-etm@open
    0x04e0:  7373 682e 636f 6d2c 756d 6163 2d36 3440  ssh.com,umac-64@
    0x04f0:  6f70 656e 7373 682e 636f 6d2c 756d 6163  openssh.com,umac
    0x0500:  2d31 3238 406f 7065 6e73 7368 2e63 6f6d  -128@openssh.com
    0x0510:  2c68 6d61 632d 7368 6132 2d32 3536 2c68  ,hmac-sha2-256,h
    0x0520:  6d61 632d 7368 6132 2d35 3132 2c68 6d61  mac-sha2-512,hma
    0x0530:  632d 7368 6131 0000 001a 6e6f 6e65 2c7a  c-sha1....none,z
    0x0540:  6c69 6240 6f70 656e 7373 682e 636f 6d2c  lib@openssh.com,
    0x0550:  7a6c 6962 0000 001a 6e6f 6e65 2c7a 6c69  zlib....none,zli
    0x0560:  6240 6f70 656e 7373 682e 636f 6d2c 7a6c  b@openssh.com,zl
    0x0570:  6962 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ib..............
    0x0580:  0000 0000                                ....
19:17:39.170347 IP 9774d56d682e549c.ssh > husky-MS-7921.40324: Flags [.], ack 1402, win 4256, options [nop,nop,TS val 1805575323 ecr 2322117203], length 0
    0x0000:  4510 0034 7d25 4000 4006 395d c0a8 0178  E..4}%@.@.9]...x
    0x0010:  c0a8 0169 0016 9d84 6b29 9b8d 8bed ef77  ...i....k).....w
    0x0020:  8010 10a0 353e 0000 0101 080a 6b9e e49b  ....5>......k...
    0x0030:  8a68 b253                                .h.S
19:17:39.170364 IP husky-MS-7921.40324 > 9774d56d682e549c.ssh: Flags [P.], seq 1402:1674, ack 483, win 237, options [nop,nop,TS val 2322117251 ecr 1805575323], length 272
    0x0000:  4500 0144 af28 4000 4006 065a c0a8 0169  E..D.(@.@..Z...i
    0x0010:  c0a8 0178 9d84 0016 8bed ef77 6b29 9b8d  ...x.......wk)..
    0x0020:  8018 00ed 3a48 0000 0101 080a 8a68 b283  ....:H.......h..
    0x0030:  6b9e e49b 0000 010c 051e 0000 0101 009d  k...............
    0x0040:  a9cc 0026 23f5 7efd 6242 4704 58d2 51f6  ...&#.~.bBG.X.Q.
    0x0050:  d1b5 74e4 830f c22d 8f6b 5a29 0216 db21  ..t....-.kZ)...!
    0x0060:  6c93 bb75 4384 9bdb 3200 0372 0840 c851  l..uC...2..r.@.Q
    0x0070:  d863 3743 8bab cf29 ab4e 41c3 caba f7b3  .c7C...).NA.....
    0x0080:  b470 d50a 3a36 23be 474d ee47 4a1d 8ca5  .p..:6#.GM.GJ...
    0x0090:  ea8b 117b d4b4 6738 75b9 0245 0dc9 5348  ...{..g8u..E..SH
    0x00a0:  543f 395d 1ddd 370b e1e3 039d 4a4a 922b  T?9]..7.....JJ.+
    0x00b0:  a5d3 f995 6faa 697c 5744 f66f 7265 928a  ....o.i|WD.ore..
    0x00c0:  3ddd e7a6 15a8 62b3 a0fc d4d9 86f1 8070  =.....b........p
    0x00d0:  02b4 ca2d fbc9 95ae 565d 6b7c 1d9b a04f  ...-....V]k|...O
    0x00e0:  9b33 0731 398f be86 1e37 423a eaf4 16c5  .3.19....7B:....
    0x00f0:  bd89 c4c7 944c 6687 68a4 e9d4 3244 f9e9  .....Lf.h...2D..
    0x0100:  b78d 9384 48f5 38e4 a3eb 4e2d bedb 4a63  ....H.8...N-..Jc
    0x0110:  ebfb 5169 4bf9 7c68 4f2c b94b b8c4 8697  ..QiK.|hO,.K....
    0x0120:  2a1e c5c7 79c2 c760 c56b 52e8 da23 47eb  *...y..`.kR..#G.
    0x0130:  38a4 ed06 124b 7015 ec7c c046 c753 e300  8....Kp..|.F.S..
    0x0140:  0000 0000                                ....
19:17:39.176536 IP 9774d56d682e549c.ssh > husky-MS-7921.40324: Flags [.], ack 1674, win 5616, options [nop,nop,TS val 1805575324 ecr 2322117251], length 0
    0x0000:  4510 0034 7d26 4000 4006 395c c0a8 0178  E..4}&@.@.9\...x
    0x0010:  c0a8 0169 0016 9d84 6b29 9b8d 8bed f087  ...i....k)......
    0x0020:  8010 15f0 2ead 0000 0101 080a 6b9e e49c  ............k...
    0x0030:  8a68 b283                                .h..
19:17:39.860670 IP 9774d56d682e549c.ssh > husky-MS-7921.40324: Flags [P.], seq 483:1059, ack 1674, win 5616, options [nop,nop,TS val 1805575499 ecr 2322117251], length 576
    0x0000:  4510 0274 7d27 4000 4006 371b c0a8 0178  E..t}'@.@.7....x
    0x0010:  c0a8 0169 0016 9d84 6b29 9b8d 8bed f087  ...i....k)......
    0x0020:  8018 15f0 1a6b 0000 0101 080a 6b9e e54b  .....k......k..K
    0x0030:  8a68 b283 0000 023c 0a1f 0000 0094 0000  .h.....<........
    0x0040:  0007 7373 682d 7273 6100 0000 0125 0000  ..ssh-rsa....%..
    0x0050:  0080 6224 4307 0ff7 edaf 4a52 bf8c fd12  ..b$C.....JR....
    0x0060:  df9e 1bd1 c778 dfb3 f76d 2e17 d697 9688  .....x...m......
    0x0070:  ef1a f3f6 d3de 6b27 3ba4 a90e 6485 da63  ......k';...d..c
    0x0080:  f72d 4b4e 636c 77f3 a0cc 90c9 df18 a469  .-KNclw........i
    0x0090:  cfbb 7801 9ae0 f329 12c4 ed33 5d52 d2b5  ..x....)...3]R..
    0x00a0:  5646 6c0b e48e dbf3 9780 ede1 2cf0 882a  VFl.........,..*
    0x00b0:  d975 aa8e 8719 72f9 fb2c c6b2 e9ba 7130  .u....r..,....q0
    0x00c0:  b2fe edba 929f d79a 9cd1 817a f9c6 4a00  ...........z..J.
    0x00d0:  fc51 0000 0101 00fe 30eb 9ba8 f578 24b6  .Q......0....x$.
    0x00e0:  da22 fbf5 e3ed bfd2 e5b3 8bad fc50 a51c  ."...........P..
    0x00f0:  bbf4 fb5b 0539 8e70 3154 6c66 6a40 20c4  ...[.9.p1Tlfj@..
    0x0100:  aa5f 7be4 6d9d 20c1 f683 fd81 50fc 7dcb  ._{.m.......P.}.
    0x0110:  4016 300f 9991 24bf 01b9 20e6 8c9f 9115  @.0...$.........
    0x0120:  fe86 87c2 50a4 d175 d2db e807 f2b7 81ae  ....P..u........
    0x0130:  ed09 cbbf d734 bf67 5470 c511 fa5a af7d  .....4.gTp...Z.}
    0x0140:  c4c3 9da2 daf2 5673 d161 b4e3 b2f7 93c3  ......Vs.a......
    0x0150:  629e 2487 bc35 3b7c 7feb 4b1d 0fcb 2d05  b.$..5;|..K...-.
    0x0160:  7300 10fc a43f 0936 b8d2 f4cb 5c9e d16b  s....?.6....\..k
    0x0170:  9d75 558a ccf4 7a8d 9030 109d 703b 6c7e  .uU...z..0..p;l~
    0x0180:  1a0d c2a7 1266 4e28 960a 057e 9254 69fb  .....fN(...~.Ti.
    0x0190:  ec70 ce6d 151b 0d19 9672 1ca8 74b0 4298  .p.m.....r..t.B.
    0x01a0:  0216 ef33 6089 bbd5 f125 6d85 6e4c fb94  ...3`....%m.nL..
    0x01b0:  ab25 f7dc 14d7 711c 14bf 4198 2ae3 83d9  .%....q...A.*...
    0x01c0:  1a3e f723 4873 4fc3 b9f6 dec9 0b0d d8ad  .>.#HsO.........
    0x01d0:  8ef1 f9b9 d5d9 d000 0000 8f00 0000 0773  ...............s
    0x01e0:  7368 2d72 7361 0000 0080 2903 9a57 3507  sh-rsa....)..W5.
    0x01f0:  0c97 fcc7 5d22 783a f9b6 8e91 7390 d9d3  ....]"x:....s...
    0x0200:  0e81 c5df 0b01 a1e6 7494 25ae 2613 8b15  ........t.%.&...
    0x0210:  c1d8 c797 9dc1 0235 e0a0 fbaa a398 56e9  .......5......V.
    0x0220:  524f 88b7 1fc1 2d33 9183 b1cc d720 06d9  RO....-3........
    0x0230:  1018 ceed 0b04 a3b6 9135 10c2 a797 8fda  .........5......
    0x0240:  e87d 156c 7dec 2a73 edd2 d623 bc41 a294  .}.l}.*s...#.A..
    0x0250:  e32c 4c81 3300 fcfa 0aff 5ea4 bac4 511d  .,L.3.....^...Q.
    0x0260:  c93c 2b88 d23b 533f b89a 8253 3a82 464b  .<+..;S?...S:.FK
    0x0270:  8048 eedb                                .H..
19:17:39.860693 IP 9774d56d682e549c.ssh > husky-MS-7921.40324: Flags [P.], seq 1059:1075, ack 1674, win 5616, options [nop,nop,TS val 1805575499 ecr 2322117251], length 16
    0x0000:  4510 0044 7d28 4000 4006 394a c0a8 0178  E..D}(@.@.9J...x
    0x0010:  c0a8 0169 0016 9d84 6b29 9dcd 8bed f087  ...i....k)......
    0x0020:  8018 15f0 83cf 0000 0101 080a 6b9e e54b  ............k..K
    0x0030:  8a68 b283 0000 000c 0a15 148b ad67 39eb  .h...........g9.
    0x0040:  27d5 7a02                                '.z.
19:17:39.860704 IP husky-MS-7921.40324 > 9774d56d682e549c.ssh: Flags [.], ack 1075, win 246, options [nop,nop,TS val 2322117941 ecr 1805575499], length 0
    0x0000:  4500 0034 af29 4000 4006 0769 c0a8 0169  E..4.)@.@..i...i
    0x0010:  c0a8 0178 9d84 0016 8bed f087 6b29 9ddd  ...x........k)..
    0x0020:  8010 00f6 3df6 0000 0101 080a 8a68 b535  ....=........h.5
    0x0030:  6b9e e54b                                k..K
19:17:39.861176 IP husky-MS-7921.40324 > 9774d56d682e549c.ssh: Flags [F.], seq 1674, ack 1075, win 246, options [nop,nop,TS val 2322117942 ecr 1805575499], length 0
    0x0000:  4500 0034 af2a 4000 4006 0768 c0a8 0169  E..4.*@.@..h...i
    0x0010:  c0a8 0178 9d84 0016 8bed f087 6b29 9ddd  ...x........k)..
    0x0020:  8011 00f6 3df4 0000 0101 080a 8a68 b536  ....=........h.6
    0x0030:  6b9e e54b                                k..K
19:17:39.866337 IP 9774d56d682e549c.ssh > husky-MS-7921.40324: Flags [F.], seq 1075, ack 1675, win 5616, options [nop,nop,TS val 1805575501 ecr 2322117942], length 0
    0x0000:  4510 0034 7d29 4000 4006 3959 c0a8 0178  E..4})@.@.9Y...x
    0x0010:  c0a8 0169 0016 9d84 6b29 9ddd 8bed f088  ...i....k)......
    0x0020:  8011 15f0 28f7 0000 0101 080a 6b9e e54d  ....(.......k..M
    0x0030:  8a68 b536                                .h.6
19:17:39.866367 IP husky-MS-7921.40324 > 9774d56d682e549c.ssh: Flags [.], ack 1076, win 246, options [nop,nop,TS val 2322117947 ecr 1805575501], length 0
    0x0000:  4500 0034 af2b 4000 4006 0767 c0a8 0169  E..4.+@.@..g...i
    0x0010:  c0a8 0178 9d84 0016 8bed f088 6b29 9dde  ...x........k)..
    0x0020:  8010 00f6 3dec 0000 0101 080a 8a68 b53b  ....=........h.;
    0x0030:  6b9e e54d                                k..M
```

Comment: `debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version dropbear_2012.55` and `debug1: no match: dropbear_2012.55`. Search for "dropbear" and "dropbear_2012.55" with your favorite search engine. If it's 2012 software, somebody else has probably seen your problem.

Comment: I have tried searching. Basically what I've found so far boiled down to "If you have OpenSSH-7.6 or later, you're SOL because of [potentially-incompatible change #4](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-7.6)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After combing through diffs between version 7.5p1 and later versions of OpenSSH, I finally found what I had to patch to get it to work.

As stated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48214424/9969468) on Stack Overflow, the cause for this is due to a change in the minimum key length to 1024 bytes that was implemented in versions 7.6 and 7.6p1. The reason for this change is because of a security concern raised by RSA in 2003 that recommended that a 1024 byte minimum be used for new keys starting in 2010 due to the rapidly increasing computer power and affordability dictated by Moore's Law ([Original source cited by Wikipedia](https://web.archive.org/web/20170417095741/https://www.emc.com/emc-plus/rsa-labs/historical/twirl-and-rsa-key-size.htm)).

## The Fix

To get around this you need to revert this change. Luckily, you only need to change one line to do that.

In `sshkey.h`, around line 50-ish a constant named `SSH_RSA_MINIMUM_MODULUS_SIZE` is defined. The line should look something like this (arrow points towards line):

```
  # define EC_POINT void
  #endif /* WITH_OPENSSL */

> #define SSH_RSA_MINIMUM_MODULUS_SIZE  1024
  #define SSH_KEY_MAX_SIGN_DATA_SIZE    (1 << 20)

  struct sshbuf;
```

All you need to do is change the value of this constant to something lower like `768` (what it was in version 7.5)

I successfully implemented this fix in the latest version (7.9p1) but in theory you could do it to any version between that and 7.6 inclusive.