# Cant ssh to cisco invalid keylength

Tags: ssh

Cant locate '''sshkey.h''' in Ubuntu files

ssh -vvv 10.x.x.x
ssh_dispatch_run_fatal: Connection to 10.70.251.49 port 22: Invalid key length

[SSH Invalid key length on embedded device](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1093883/ssh-invalid-key-length-on-embedded-device)

Comment: Why do you believe there should be a `sshkey.h` file? what issue are you actually trying to solve?

Comment: OK so the answer in the link you added assumes that you have downloaded the OpenSSH source code and are building your own version of the SSH programs - you should find `sshkey.h` in the top level of the source tree

Comment: what are you ssh -ing into? some devices use various other types of encryption. perhaps your are using the wrong cypher for the device? I see where you got the idea there might be a file of that name, but contextually, I think you might be better off modifying a config file and editing a source library. what version of ssh are you using anyway? what ubuntu version?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

fixed by fixing the client Cisco:

```
conf t
crypto key zerosize rsa
crypto key generate rsa modulus 2048
end
```

Comment: This worked for me as well, it removes all keys and then generates one of size 2048. Modern SSH clients fail when the server's RSA key is not large enough